# By mistake excuded binary references from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

By mistake I hit "exclude from project" on the bin in my Visual Studio project. Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: I don't think your bin folder SHOULD be included in your project to begin with.

Comment: You don't need the bin folder in your solution in order to debug/compile.  Any particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: I am writing a number of libraries and was given this project as a way to provide a platform. This was what the structure was when I got it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the top of the solution explorer, click the "Show All Files", find the ghosted file you excluded and then right click it and select "Include in project".

Comment: The folder shows up but the "include in project" is grayed out

Answer (score 3):

In your solution explorer at the very top the second button will toggle the "Show All Files".  You may have to hit the refresh button after that.  At any rate that will show you all files even those that are not included in your project.  Right click on the file and select the include in project from the context menu to add it back to your project.